# where does gnome-display-properties save the different configurations?

Tags: gnome, display, external-monitor

I use `gnome-display-properties` to configure the external screens that I attach to my laptop at home and in the office. `gnome-display-properties` cleverly remembers which screen is which, and automatically sets the display up when the screen is plugged.

For example, in `gnome-display-properties`, the monitor shows as "Monitor: Samsung Electric Company 24''", I wonder where is this info pulled from?

Where is this information saved?

Comment: Could you check on your ~/.config/monitors.xml ? I just briefly Googled it but not sure if it is the correct answer.

Comment: yes, the xml shows things like 'SAM' which I believe correspond to the Samsung monitor. In gnome-display-properties, the monitor shows as "Monitor: Samsung Electric Company 24''", I wonder where is this info pulled from.

Comment: Perhaps there are some other files/settings that can link the SAM to 'Samsung Electric Company 24'. But I am not expert in that anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information is coming from the monitor's [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data). To check, you can install the package `read-edid` and run

```
sudo get-edid | parse-edid
```

That should output some info including the monitor section we previously had in our xorg.conf files, e.g.:

```
Section "Monitor"
    # Block type: 2:0 3:ff
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fc
    Identifier "DELL U2311H"
    VendorName "DEL"
    ModelName "DELL U2311H"
    # Block type: 2:0 3:ff
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fc
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fd
    HorizSync 30-83
    VertRefresh 56-76
    # Max dot clock (video bandwidth) 170 MHz
    # DPMS capabilities: Active off:yes  Suspend:yes  Standby:yes

    Mode    "1920x1080" # vfreq 60.000Hz, hfreq 67.500kHz
        DotClock    148.500000
        HTimings    1920 2008 2052 2200
        VTimings    1080 1084 1089 1125
        Flags   "+HSync" "+VSync"
    EndMode
    # Block type: 2:0 3:ff
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fc
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fd
EndSection
```

Note the three letter VendorName.

Answer (score 17):

Adding to htorque's answer and converting JohanSJA's comment to an answer:

> Where is this information saved?

In `~/.config/monitors.xml`.

Comment: This is what I needed to delete in order to get my flanking monitors to turn back on.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: it answers the question. The currently accepted answer nevertheless provides very interesting info